# How to execute the bash's sudo command using execvp function?

Tags: c++, exec, execvp

I have an executable, `a.out` which takes several `command-line` arguments. This executable needs to be run with `root` privileges, like `sudo ./a.out arg1 arg2 ...` .

How should I do this using the `execvp` system call in C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 char *args[5];

 args[0]="sudo";
 args[1]="./a.out";
 args[2]="arg1";
 args[3]="arg2";
 args[4]=NULL;
 execvp("sudo", args);
```

The shell splits the given command into whitespace-delimited words. The first word gets looked up in `PATH`, and all the words are passed as parameters to the command.

Sinec `execvp()` will search the `PATH` for you, you can simply pass "sudo" as the command, then the arguments to the command. Note that the first argument to the command is the command's name.

The command you're executing is "sudo", so that's the first argument; then the remaining words as individual arguments, passed as an array.

Comment: Yup, overlooked that. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is not working: ?
execvp("/usr/bin/sudo", "./a.out arg1 erg2").

Comment: What exactly is the first argument here ?